# How to present a modal view controller when the app enters in foreground?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, methods, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm trying to present a Modal View Controller when the app enters in foreground.. These are my files:
AppDelegate.m :

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MainViewController.h"    
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
        MainViewController * vc = [[MainViewController alloc]init];
        [vc myMethodHere];       
    }
```

MainViewController.h :

```
//[..]
-(void) myMethodHere;
```

MainViewController.m :

```
-(void)myMethodHere{
    NSLog(@"myMethodHere Activated.");
    TWTweetComposeViewController *tweetViewController = [[TWTweetComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:tweetViewController animated:YES];
}
```

NSLog(@"myMethodHere Activated.") works.. so I can't understand why "presentModalViewController" doesn't! What should I edit/add? Maybe a delay? Thanks for your help..

p.s. I know my english sucks.. Forgive me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't rely on the methods in your app delegate for this (even though it seems like the obvious solution) because it creates unnecessary coupling between your application delegate and the view controller. Instead, you can have `MainViewController` listen for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive` notification, and present the tweet composer view controller in response to this notification.

First, register for the notification in `-viewDidLoad`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(myMethodHere) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```

Now, when this notification is received when your app returns from the background, `myMethodHere` will be invoked.

Lastly, remember to remove yourself as an observer when the view unloads.

```
- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
}
```